# how to integrate vlc media player in an android webview app

Tags: android

I downloaded yaplayer app (contains vlc libraries) from github for DASH AND HLS support. The app opens in video view and can effectively play .ts files.

I need the main activity to be webview and not video view but the app should be able to call the vlc media player to play videos. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please be specific about what part is not working and show the code.

Comment: what i need actually is a repository to an android webview app that can call either vlc or exoplayer intent to play HLS streams. Any help will be appreciated.